# Redirect after save or edit data?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

If I have 2-30 record it nothing wrong in my screen just scroll down.

But when i have 30++ record it take more time Where the record saved or the record just edited.

My question is, can I redirect to the record just saved or edited?
It's easy using link such as:

```html
<a href="#yourdataeditedhere">Go to your edited record</a>
And than my screen sroll to the #yourdataeditedhere<br>
No need to sroll like link menu.
```

```html
<div id="yourdataeditedhere">Record Just Edited</div>
```

My problem is:

**index.php**

```php
<html>
    <form name="frmMain" method="post" action="edit.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="hdnCmd" value="">  
    <input type="hidden" name="produkid" value="<? print $row['produkid']; ?>">
   <input type="submit" name="simpan" value="Simpan">
   <input type="text" name="produkname">
   <input type="button" value="Update" OnClick="frmMain.hdnCmd.value='Updateprodukname';frmMain.submit();">
</form>
```

**simpan.php**

```php
<? if($_POST["hdnCmd"] == "Updateprodukname")
{
    if (empty($produkname))
    {   
    header("location:index.php?status=Error&Action=Editprodukname&produkid=$produkid#produkid=$produkid");
    }
    else
    {
    $myqry="UPDATE produk SET produkname='$produkname' WHERE produkid='$produkid' LIMIT 1";
    mysql_query($myqry) or die(mysql_error());
    header("location:index.php?status=success&produkid=$produkid#produkid=$produkid");
    exit;
    }
}
?>
```

I try add `&produkid=$produkid` and `#produkid=$produkid` at header simpan.php

But when record, it fails or edited when page refresh my screen on top.

What I need is, like some reply forum. After I reply the other people reply message, after refresh my screen go to page of his/her reply message and my screen scrolled to his/her reply message not on top or bottom.

Comment: You are open to `SQL Injection`.

Comment: Read more: https://geekflare.com/sql-injection-prevention-php/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because you insert $variable into a string.

Try:

```html
header('Location: index.php?status=success&produkid=' . $produkid . '#produkid=' . $produkid);
```